# Application for monitoring all applications that are using the internet in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, internet, process, monitoring

Can anyone introduce me a Mac OS X application that monitors all network activity such as what applications are now connected to the internet and how much bandwidth they use (I mean show bandwidth separately for each application)?

Comment: same question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101474/finding-per-process-bandwidth-usage-on-the-mac

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to buy any fancy GUI software, you can try `nettop` in `Terminal.app`

Use the arrow keys or <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd> keys for scrolling. Use `-n` option to disable IP address reverse resolution.

Example of an output:

```
                                                               interface           state      packets in        bytes in
iTunes.35506                                                                                           0           0 B
    tcp6 *.3689<->*.*                                                             Listen
    tcp4 *:3689<->*:*                                                             Listen
    tcp4 *:57929<->*:*                                                            Listen
Last.fm.35511                                                                                          0           0 B
    tcp4 127.0.0.1:33367<->*:*                                       lo0          Listen
    tcp4 127.0.0.1:32213<->*:*                                       lo0          Listen
Spotify.35589                                                                                        380         227 KiB
    tcp4 192.168.2.18:57621<->192.168.2.15:52137                     en1     Established             194          34 KiB
    tcp4 *:57621<->*:*                                                            Listen
    tcp4 *:49858<->*:*                                                            Listen
    tcp4 192.168.2.18:58339<->193.182.8.12:4070                      en1     Established             186         192 KiB
    tcp4 127.0.0.1:4371<->*:*                                        lo0          Listen
    tcp4 127.0.0.1:4381<->*:*                                        lo0          Listen
```

Pretty awesome right? Best of all, `nettop` is embedded in OSX (well at least in Mountain Lion).

Comment: This is perfect, and if you press the <kbd>d</kbd> key, you can toggle between cumulative totals and the "diff" mode (how much each app used in the last second).

Comment: press `c-for simplified view` for more help `h`

Comment: Is there any way nettop can real-time _sort_ such that processes using the most (current snapshot instead of historical) bandwidth are listed first?

Answer (score 14):

[Rubbernet](http://rubbernetapp.com) looks good.

> Rubbernet provides a breakdown of per-app network usage, so you can
>   quickly detect apps that phone home, connect to certain servers
>   without your knowledge, or blame the app that's slowing down your
>   network.

[image]

Comment: This app is exactly what the OP is asking for. It works.

Answer (score 6):

Try [LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html):

> A firewall protects your computer
>   against unwanted guests from the
>   Internet. But who protects your
>   private data from being sent out?
>   Little Snitch does!

[image]

Comment: I have LittleSnitch but it just show what application use internet don't show BW for each application

Comment: it does show which apps are currently using bandwidth which at times is enough...

Comment: You can click on the application in the window and it shows the graph of the network usage per application.

Answer (score 4):

Rubbernet is something that does everything you ask for.  HOWEVER be warned.  It is expensive, and it does not come with the features you'd expect for in basic freeware, let alone an expensive piece of software for monitoring usage.    Limitations include:

- loses all measured data when laptop sleeps
- loses all measured data when VPN status changes
- no "total measure" on the summary page: only the individual amounts used per app

Comment: Furthermore, the support is non-existent.   No documentation, no response to tickets...

Answer (score 4):

In OSX **10.9** simply use the built in **Activity Monitor**:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5890?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to show recent network bandwidth usage per application.  Were you able to?

Answer (score 2):

If you have some Command Line know how, there are some Unix tools you may be able to take advantage of.

**[iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/):** Won't give you a per application breakdown but it will give you a breakdown by remote host. This means that you can at least see who you're sending information too and how much. It's also installable via [DarwinPorts](http://iftop.darwinports.com/).

**nethogs:** This one may not run on OS X, though it would be more informative. Unfortunately, it's probably a moot point.

You can also check out this other question for more information: [Bandwidth Usage in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/32932/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-application-using-most-of-bandwidth-in-linux).

Comment: nethogs on ubuntu is my best friend... I am searching similar for mac.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 4, [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) shows the bandwidth usage of the top 5 applications.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out Little Snitch, having the same basic problem (it seems) as the OP, and having been so disappointed with rubbernet (I weep for my $40).

Little Snitch is exactly what the OP asks for, and has every feature I can dream of in exploring related problems to those implied by the OP's question.

It *does* report the total bandwidth used by each application individually, and even presents a graph of any selected application or group of applications!      Once you realise that you can select one or more rows in the Network Monitor graph, and ask for the collated info of those by presing the info button, it is simple to use.  It survives changes of network status seamlessly.

It has a demo that lasts 3 hours, so you can't go wrong.

I think it is the perfect answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Incidentally, it's "outbound firewall" feature just showed me that I am running an app that is phoning home rather unexpectedly!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to use, originally called Ethereal, there's [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

I never used it myself, but I've tried in the past and it does just about anything.

If you want just to see general bandwidth, use Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lion or Mountain Lion I would suggest **[Icefloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/)**

If you are using Snow Leopard I would suggest **[NoobProof](http://www.hanynet.com/noobproof/)**

They are both free to use and will accomplish your needs

Comment: The description doesn't look like these show individual applications' bandwidth. Can you confirm this feature exists, maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: @Daniel Beck - In the Noobproof description it states you can tune the bandwidth manage black lists and create self-configuration tools called injectors.

Comment: I only found "Limiting bandwidth" which is different from "showing actually used bandwidth", which is what the OP asks for. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Daniel Beck - In the 1st paragraph 7th line down it states you can tune the bandwidth

Comment: Tuning here means you can set how much network bandwidth can be used by a process I think.  That has nothing to do with showing how much a process naturally uses, for instance to see if a certain application is very active when not be explicitly used, or to search for a rootkit/virus/malware.

Answer (score 0):

**Shameless plug:** I had the same need and couldn't find anything that was quite right, so I wrote one. Please take a look at AppTerrain (https://noisycatlabs.com), available on the Mac app store. I'm very pleased with how it turned out and keep it running in the background all the time. I'm actively updating this app so feature requests are welcome!

Apologies for resurrecting an old question but I stumbled upon this in my search so I wanted add my update. Thanks!