# Find bandwidth used by process

Tags: macos, mac, networking, process, monitoring

Something is using a lot of bandwidth according to iStat menu. But I can't figure out what's doing it. lsof -i only shows what's connected but not how much bandwidth is being used

Please do no link with 
[Application for monitoring all applications that are using the internet in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/50515/application-for-monitoring-all-applications-that-are-using-the-internet-in-mac-os). It is not the same issue since that post shows how to list hosts to which my computer is connected to and their associated speeds but not the processes which is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the other topic help you anyway, for example [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) includes a network traffic monitor.

[image]

---

Another option is [ProteMac Meter](http://www.protemac.com/Meter/), which I haven't used, but its manual includes relevant screen shots (the following being called *Realtime Traffic Chart*):

[image]

Comment: "Little Snitch" is awesome! That's what I use too.

Answer (score 1):

This is Mac specific, but I recently found [Rubbernet](http://rubbernetapp.com/). Its a really great app that allows you to see the per application network usage of your Mac plus it supports Remote Monitoring. You can install a Rubbernet plugin any Mac that you have administrative access and then monitor the per application bandwidth utilization of all the Macintosh on your network from your own computer.

It does cost money (30 Euros on their website but for some reason its $19.99 on the Mac App Store but they have a fully functional Free Trial on their website. I haven't bought the app yet, so I can not confirm that you can buy one license for the app and then install the plugin on any number of Macs for now additional charge. But that seems to be the situation.

The Developers are the same folks who do the Linkinus IRC Client.

Another option that is not quite as good as it does not have any kind of remote monitoring mechnaism and didn't seem to do as good a job is [OS Track](http://ostrack-app.com/). Its also available on the Mac App Store for free.