# How to turn off things that use Internet on mac (OSX 10.8)

Tags: internet, modem, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-air, internet-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application for monitoring all applications that are using the internet in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/50515/application-for-monitoring-all-applications-that-are-using-the-internet-in-mac-o)

I've recently received MacBook Air with OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and i'm not so into the details of the system yet. I've recently bought a modem which works very well, but the problem is that the modems ISP prices for internet are really high and due to lack of competitor ISPs which have good connection and speed in the location i'll be using it, I have no other choice.

So i would like to lower the "internet usage" of mac to minimum (Only to things that i'm using and are required for minimum functionality). In other words i would like to turn off any background services or processes that use internet (Update services and likes).

Comment: Sounds good to me, start turning them off.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to start :)

Comment: You don't know how to turn them off, or you don't know which to turn off?  Really, we can't guess what services you have running and which ones you need.  So unless you're asking HOW to stop them, then this question is "Not constructive" (IMO) as it would depend on your personal needs and situation.  We also appreciate some effort on your side. What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck? :)

Comment: I would like to know the list of services or names of applications which are known to use internet in background (check updates or smth.) and how to disable internet usage or completely disable if they are not critical. I've turned off automatic checking of system updates first. And i would like to know what to turn off next. I can provide any information needed (like list of processes or smth.)

Comment: Check out [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Comment: The linked question gives you a few methods to check what is using the internet and also disable apps (try LittleSnitch, it'll probably do exactly what you want). If that doesn't solve your problem, please let me know.