# How can I see which programs/users are talking to which network addresses and how much ? (Unix/Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, unix, display, bandwidth, top

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find out what application using most of bandwidth in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/32932/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-application-using-most-of-bandwidth-in-linux)

I'm interested in which programs are using my network connection and how much.

I wondered if there was a thing which is to network use as htop is to cpu/memory use?

I'd like a list of other computers currently connected to, which users/programs have made the connection,  sorted in order of load, and displayed in realtime.

I've played with netstat a bit, and it tells me what I'm connected to, but not where the heavy traffic is. Wireshark on the other hand gives me far too much information.

Comment: I agree. This question is a duplicate, and the answer is "nethogs"

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any software which will tell you (directly) which program is using how much bandwidth, but you can largely solve the problem by monitoring the bandwidth, seeing what ports are using the bandwidth and then working out which program (and thus protocol) is associated with the traffic.  [ I suspect - but could be wrong - in positing that you won't find a package that will directly link traffic to a process, as traffic needs to pass through the kernel and all the bandwidth programs I've seen - ignoring Android ones - look at whats going across the interface by interfacing with libpcap]

IPTraf should be able to provide you with a reasonable balance between too much and too little information, and is easy to use. (In your case, IP traffic monitor and Statistical Breakdowns are probably of most use).

If the traffic relates to a service running on your machine you can find the name of the service by typing `fuser -n [udp|tcp]` port which will give you the PID of the process associated with the traffic.