# AWS Ec2 sending out > 10TB a month

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have received some alerts from AWS that my instance is sending out large amounts of data to some websites. Close to and greater than 10TB a month.

I have wordpress and apache installed on this ec2.

I ran `iftop` from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/32932/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-application-using-most-of-bandwidth-in-linux) answer.

I get this result

```
ip-xx-xxx-x-xx.xx-xxx-x.compute.xxxxx      => xxx.xx.xx.x 4.33kb  48.2kb  59.6kb                                                                                  <=                                                                                             141kb  3.45Mb  4.18Mb
ip-xx-xxx-x-xx.xx-xxx-x.compute.xxxxx      => yyy.yyy.yy.yyy 20.7kb  23.9kb  9.22kb
```

If I run nethogs I get

```
?     root     my-ec2-ipaddress:randomportnumber-externalipaddress:80                                                                                                                                   0.021       0.182 KB/sec
?     root     my-ec2-ipaddress:randomportnumber-externalipaddress:80                                                                                                                                   0.021       0.12 KB/sec
?     root     my-ec2-ipaddress:randomportnumber-externalipaddress:80                                                                                                                                   0.021       0.185 KB/sec
?     root     my-ec2-ipaddress:randomportnumber-externalipaddress:80                                                                                                                                   0.021       0.152 KB/sec
```

How do I find the offending program ?

Comment: Try using `netstat -tupn` to get name/pid of program that is using those ports. Then `ps faux` could be used to see if that process was spawned by other process.

Comment: /usr/bin/host is sending out all that data

Comment: What user is running that process? Look like it might be case of attack like this one: https://nixtree.com/blog/detecting-wordpress-outbound-bruteforce-attack-from-server/